# MPMoviePlayerController crashes when calling stop in iOS7

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios7

Recently i've been with a very strange issue. It only happens in iOS 7. I use MPMoviePlayerController to play a stream from the Web. It was working perfect....until I switch to iOS7. Now it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS whenever I call stop. When the playbackFinishes I also call stop and it does not give me any errors, only when I press the stop button.

Did someone had the same issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have. I attached a breakpoint where I called stop and stepped through. In the console this showed that it threw this error: "[__NSCFType _postNotificationName:object:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" Do you get something similar when you try?

Comment: It seems like on iOS7 the PlaybackFinish notification is called also when you press stop. It happens so that I was stopping everything twice and over releasing resources... sorry, I did not have any issues like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like on iOS7 the PlaybackFinish notification is called also when you press stop. It happens so that I was stopping everything twice and over releasing resources... sorry, I did not have any issues like yours.